# Create Textarea input box in Zend 2 Form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I'm trying to set a textarea in a Zend Form but it always creates an input type text box.

I read some code using the Zend\Form\Element\Textarea but still no luck

This is how I am doing it in my ProjectForm.php:

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'summary',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Resumen',
            ),
        ));
```

And in Project.php I have this

```
    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name'     => 'summary',
        'required' => true,
        'filters'  => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'StringLength',
                'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'      => 1,
                    'max'      => 500,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )));
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show your View where u are outputting the text area field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I was calling `echo $this->formInput` instead of `echo $this->formTextarea` viewHelper.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the type in attributes:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name'       => 'summary',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id'    => 'summary'
        'type'  => 'textarea',
        'class' => '',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Resumen',
        ),
    )
);
```